# Any method to recognize or demarcate web traffic based on whether it is coming from a desktop client or browser

Tags: python, vb.net, iis, windows-client

We have an app which can be accessed both via Browser and a custom Windows Desktop client. The web application is running on Windows IIS. Is there a way to differentiate whether traffic is from an Web Browser or Windows desktop client.

We don't own the server application. I know ways to recognize the browser in a server side app, and write JS or server side rules.

However we need a middleman program which listens to the traffic and then depending on a simple rule disallow previleges to the desktop client.

The desktop client is Windows native client written in VB.

Preferred language Python

Comment: Is the desktop app communicating over the same port as the browser? (http is typically 80 i think ), because if its a different port, block the port on the local machine. If it IS the same port, then you may have check the user agent, going out, and then filter based on that.

Comment: I'm very curious what the situation is where you would be doing this in the first place... blog post? :)

Comment: Take a look at the http headers with your Python middle-man. In vb.net this would be via Request.UserAgent and Request.Browser.Browser, but you said that you already could recognise the browser in a server side app. Aren't you wanting to write a server-side app to act as "middleman"? Or do you want to be able to configure IIS to do it?

Comment: Both are running on Port 80.

The desktop app is different from browser. We want to limit the desktop app to a certain list of IP Addresses. We cannot stop for universal access because web app is meant for just about anyone, while desktop app is something meant for some office users.

Note the application is not written by us nor maintained by us. The original developers are unable to do anything.
I am searching for a way to set up a Firewall kind of script which will sit on the edge and monitor PORT 80 traffic identifies whether it is browser based let's it pass, if it's desktop apply rules

Comment: What about a windows firewall group policy denying the desktop EXE from accessing the network for all users except those given explicit access?